# What's the meaning of mov 0x8(%r14,%r15,8),%rax

Tags: linux, disassembly, att

In here what's the meaning of 0x8(%r14,%r15,8), I know 0x8(%r14,%r15,8) is SRC, but I don't understand why use two register %r14 and %r15 in here, and I don't understand how to cal the src address.
Thanks so much for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Information pulled from http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/papers/x86-asm/asm.html

**AT&T Addressing:**

Memory Address Reference:  Address_or_Offset(%base_or_offset, %Index_Register, Scale)

Final Address Calculation: Address_or_Offset + %base_or_offset + [Scale * %Index_Reg]

Example:

```
mov (%esi,%ebx,4), %edx         /* Move the 4 bytes of data at address ESI+4*EBX into EDX. */
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. It's very helpful for me.